# XAML window containing a sub XAML window

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to, quite simply, have a main XAML document which then holds several XAML documents. So let's say I have a Grid with three columns: the first would be XAML document A, the second XAML document B and the third XAML document C.

I've seen it done with a TabControl, but when I try to do it with a Grid I get an error, even when I made my sub XAML document only have a simple textbox in it.

My XAML looks like this (for the main window):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="250*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


        <local:CharacterDetails/>
</Grid>
```

The error I get says 'Add value to collection of type 'System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection' threw an exception.'

I'm going to guess that you can't put a sub XAML inside a grid like this. If this is the case, in what controls CAN I put them?

Thanks for your time.

[Here is an image of the solution explorer, so you can see what CharacterDetails is.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEQnX.jpg)

Also, here is what's contained within that:

```
<Window x:Class="MVVMTest.CharacterDetails"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="CharacterDetails" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <TextBlock>Hello!</TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Comment: It's perfectly reasonably to have a xaml within xaml. Is `CharacterDetails` a `UserControl`?

Comment: It's another XAML window, like the main window.

Comment: Ah, a `Window` can't contain another `Window`. A `Window` must be the root of the visual tree, your "sub-xaml" should be `UserControl`.

Comment: In general, I find it easiest to make _everything_ a `UserControl`, and then host a single root `UserControl` in my `Window`.

Comment: Many many thanks! It works like a charm!